# Modbus IP with Simply Modbus TCP

Tags: ethernet, modbus

```
include SPI.h
include Ethernet.h
include Modbus.h
include ModbusIP.h

//Modbus Registers Offsets (0-9999)
const int SENSOR_IREG = 100;
//Used Pins
const int sensorPin = A0;

//ModbusIP object
ModbusIP mb;

long ts;


// Set Port to 502
EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(502);

void setup() {
  //Assign the modbus device ID.  
  regBank.setId(1);

    byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };  

    byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 177 };  

    mb.config(mac, ip);

    // Add SENSOR_IREG register - Use addIreg() for analog Inputs
    mb.addIreg(SENSOR_IREG);

    ts = millis();

}

void loop() {

   //Call once inside loop() - all magic here
   mb.task();


   if (millis() > ts + 2000) {  
       ts = millis();

       mb.Ireg(SENSOR_IREG, analogRead(sensorPin));
   }
}
```

I am trying to read data from the first analog pin through ModbusTCP using SimplyModbusTCP but I keep getting errors when I poll my Arduino. I am using an Arduino UNO with a Ethernet Shield W5100 and [Modbus Library](https://github.com/andresarmento/modbus-arduino). I am request data from Ip address 192.168.1.177 Port:502 Slave:1 and Function Code:03. The error I get is "Error 66 occurred at TCP Read in SMT8.0.vi. LabVIEW: The network connection was closed by the peer."

Comment: did you test the Ethernet shield with some basic Ethernet library example?

Comment: Yes I did and it worked fine. I can even ping the unit through cmd.

Comment: did you set the register address 100? try 101 in client too

Comment: Tried both, with same results

Comment: Removed that and I am still getting the same result

Comment: still error 66?

Comment: input registers is function 04

Comment: II get the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like SimplyModbus was the problem, used [Modbus poll](https://www.modbustools.com/download.html) and was able to read data.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create the Ethernet server. The library creates the server and your server takes the port first.

Modbus function code to read Input registers is 04.

Comment: I removed that line and still get the same results

Comment: Tried function code 4 and got the same result

Comment: try again register 101